# Creating a new short-cut in GNOME3

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I would like to add *Firefox Developer Edition* to my "Applications Menu" in *GNOME 3*:

The *Firefox Developer Edition* only opens when I do (open it directly using the shell):

`/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/firefox`

And then the icon appears:

[image]

You will also notice the standard *Firefox* icon.

I would like the *Firefox Developer Edition* to alway be there in the *Applications Menu* to click.

Here's my kernel and Fedora info:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.5.10-200.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 18 14:21:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[me@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
```

The location of the executable is `/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/firefox`

I tried creating a `/home/me/Desktop/firefox-dev.desktop` with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/firefox.sh
Icon=/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

But that didn't work.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Update:**

The problem exists after I removed the `.sh` from the `Exec` path:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/firefox
Icon=/home/me/Downloads/firefox-75.0b10/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

Comment: is "firefox.sh" in the Exec line a typo?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be.

Comment: I changed it to just "firefox" - issue stil exists.

Comment: I don't have Gnome3 available but can you try placing the desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications  ?

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Add it as an answer an I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [developer gnome manual](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) I suggest placing the desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` or if you want it available for all users in  `/usr/share/applications`

> These desktop files contain metadata about your application, and play
>   a central role in integrating the program with the GNOME and other
>   standards compliant desktops. The template presented here is the most
>   basic possible. The file can be linguistically translated so your
>   applications name can appear in the user's native language.
>
> Place this file in the /usr/share/applications directory so that it is
>   accessible by everyone, or in ~/.local/share/applications if you only
>   wish to make it accessible to a single user. Which is used should
>   depend on whether your application is installed systemwide or into a
>   user's home directory. GNOME monitors these directories for changes,
>   so simply copying the file to the right location is enough to register
>   it with the desktop. 1